Preallocation changes in Postgresql 16
We have PostgreSQL server, which currently runs PostgreSQL 15 on compressed btrfs.
I tried to migrate DB to PostgreSQL 16, and found that data is not being compressed for PostgreSQL 16 server. One of the possible reason why btrfs won't compress data is data preallocation.
When running "compsize" tool, I indeed see that PostgreSQL preallocating data and it is not compressed (there is separate "preallocated" entry in output).
I am wondering if there were preallocation related changes in PG16, and if it is possible to disable preallocation in PostgreSQL 16?
Long discussion on lore.kernel.org about exactly this issue.

PostgreSQL has no idea what the underlying file system is and doesn't do anything special when storing data, so my guess is that you either have something configured differently on the OS or file system level, or that some unrelated change in PostgreSQL triggers a different behavior of the file system. May I add that keeping a database on a compressed file system is questionable practice.

maybe commit 00d1e02be24987180115e371abaeb84738257ae2 new in v16. https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=00d1e02be24987180115e371abaeb84738257ae2

@LaurenzAlbe there are many different APIs how data can be stored. My understanding is if client uses something like fallocate, then btrfs can't handle it gracefuly.
For us it is necessity, our dataset is large, but compressable by ratio 7 which saves a lot of disk space but also disk ops.

I think you should discuss this on the pgsql-hackers mailing list.
